# Como abrir diferentes páginas web usando o while

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, while

Gostaria que o programa executasse a repetição de um comando 3 vezes: esperar 10 segundos para abrir uma página web. Para que essa repetição ocorra defini o código abaixo:

```
import time
import webbrowser

total_breaks = 3
break_count = 0

while(break_count < total_breaks):
    time.sleep(10)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zywDiFdxopU")
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwOU3bnuU0k")
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2WzocbSd2w")
    break_count = break_count + 1
```

Mas acontece que as páginas são abertas ao mesmo tempo. Gostaria que na primeira vez ele abra a página a e na segunda vez ele abra a página b e na terceira vez ele abra a página c. Como faço para que ao invés do programa abrir todas as páginas web, ele abra uma página a cada vez que o programa seja executado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cada `open` tem um `sleep` correspondente. Isso já te dá uma pista de que seu laço não pode ser composto de vários `open` do jeito que está, e sim apenas um.

Como você vai ter apenas um `open`, você precisa variar o parâmetro dele. Como os possíveis parâmetros são fixos, vamos colocá-los em uma tupla e iterar sobre ela com um `for` em vez de um `while`:

```
import time
import webbrowser

enderecos = ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zywDiFdxopU", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwOU3bnuU0k", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2WzocbSd2w");

for endereco in enderecos:
  webbrowser.open(endereco)
  time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Pablo, tentei executar desse jeito, mas aparece um erro de sintaxe. O seu rodou sem problemas?

Comment: Estou sem acesso a um interpretador Python agora, mas a alteração que eu fiz não deveria ter dado erro. Qual é a mensagem e em qual linha é?

Comment: Acho que agora vai. Tente novamente aí.

Comment: A mensagem é: "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 6
for (endereco in enderecos):^SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Ele aponta especificamente para os dois pontos.

Comment: Tinha parêntesis onde não devia. Tente de novo sem eles.